# How do I write an exclude rule so that my urls can still use http?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How do I write an exclude rule so that my urls can still use http?

I want to have an exclude rule for index.php?route=ebay/openbay/* but are not sure how to do this?

I have tried the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php?route=ebay/openbay/*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php?route=ebay/openbay/*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
    RewriteRule ^download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/index\.php\?route=ebay/openbay/*
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/index\.php\?route=ebay/openbay/
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase\.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```